# Check in which polygon a point is with Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

Folks,

Say I have two datasets, one with polygons attributed to districts...

[image]

...and one with points attributed to places.

[image]

I want to add to that places dataset a new column stating in what neighborhood each place is located.

This is what I've been doing, but there are some POINT(nan nan) on the way, which are skipped. So the resulting list is smaller than the original column.

```html
district = []

for i in places['geometry']:
  for j,k in zip(neighborhoods.geometry,neighborhoods.district):
    if i.within(j):
      district.append(k)
    else:
      pass
```

I'd like to get an empty value for each "POINT (nan nan)".

Comment: Why not interating over the list of points? If you drop the dupliactes (in you second DataFrame) first it may take not so much time.

Comment: I am doing that, but there are some POINT(nan nan) messing around. Will clarify with some code.

Comment: You should drop them too. How else would you evaluate?

Comment: Can't. I have other information on those records that is still necessary. Just added my code there.

Comment: Can you refill the NaN with some dummy values?

Comment: Hm. Or maybe separate a dictionary so I can iterate and then map back. Maybe this is a way.

Comment: Can you please add your DataFrames (or the head of these) to your question. That makes it easier to work with it. Pictures are difficult to copy.

Comment: Next time, for sure. The midway dictionary worked pretty well. Thanks!!! Had to use something like for h,i: for j,k: if i in j: l = (h,k) append(l)

Comment: You can just use spatial join in geopandas: https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins